# DOM manipulation and local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css

Create a webpage where you can add notes, be able to edit them, and also delete them. You can design the interface to be as simple or as fancy as you want, as long as the user is able to make new notes, and edit/delete old notes. You could have the notes in a list, in a grid, or any other way. Please keep in mind that you dont have to use jquery or any other library only simple javascript. How should i get started.

Comment: I need help on proceeding with above mentioned project. How should i get started.

Comment: You start by designing your application, then you code it.

Comment: By learning HTML+CSS+JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you can use HTML5 localStorage to do the save,edit,delete operations.

to store a value u can use :

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("note", "This is my simple note");
```

the first parameter is key and the second is value. value can be a simple string or integer , ... and also can be a list of object, array, json array , ...

To retrieve value you can use :

```
localStorage.getItem("note");
```

which the parameter is the key you used for store your value.

also you can display the value in html like this :

```
document.getElementById("noteSection").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("note");
```

To remove anitem, u can use :

```
localStorage.removeItem("note");
```

here I create a simple example to do save/load/delete data :

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/0dohjw8t/1/

UPDATE :

for edit is almost the same process.

you can see an example here :

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/0dohjw8t/2/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but to edit anything what should be done

Comment: I update the answer with an example for edit/update value, just write something to update it, and then if you click on load data you can see the updated value. ofcourse this is a simple example, you can read more about it and try to make something which is fit your needs.

Comment: in the problem it is mentioned that I have to edit the existing notes

Comment: I want to assign the value of the input in the newly created division element and then display it as above. Here is my code I am not getting any error but i am not getting any output by clicking on loadData, where I am making mistakes :   function loadData(){
 var newItem = document.createElement("div");
 newItem.id='textFeild';
 newItem.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("note");
}

Comment: you should use this at end of your function to actually add your new div to body : document.body.appendChild(newItem);

Comment: worked thankyou sir

Comment: I have used localstorage in my code but still after i refresh my page  data gets lost how to fix that.